# Is TreeMap suitable for a input with million distinct records where sorting by value occurs regularly

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, treemap

I am planning to use a tree map in the below scenario.

> Given a list of users(around million distinct users) I need to keep track of the number of visits for each one of them.
>   The users can visit the same site multiple times. It is a single machine and in memory
>   I need to maintain a ranking of each user based on no of visits in the map or any other data structure I will be using.
>   For the code written the method of getting the user ranking and altering the view count and sorting again would be called more frequently than the new users visiting.
>   The ranking of the user will be again based on view count which would be the value in my TreeMap and key would be the distinct user id.
>   Every time the view count changes for a user the value is changed for the respective id and I need to sort the huge TreeMap again.
>   Is there any other datastructure which would help me maintain a huge sorted list of users based on their visit count or is the TreeMap good enough.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap

Comment: I doubt a treap would be helpful in this case. You're just trading one balanced BST for a randomized BST.

Comment: `TreeMap` doesn't support sorting by value.  (Additionally, for your actual use case: who wants to track all the users who've visited once and never again?  And do you really need exact visit counts?)

Comment: if it doesn't have to be within the java vm: http://redis.io/topics/data-types#sorted-sets would also work well

Comment: @LouisWasserman It is not the exact use case. I came across a similiar question and had provided an inefficent answer in an interview.I am unable to post the exact question in this situation therefore I just have posted a part of it with different wordings

Comment: @zapl unfortunately trying to solve it using java vm. But the link was good .Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no. TreeMap is not meant to be sorted by value.

What you can do is using a priority queue, based the view count of each user. It allows efficient insertion in O(log(n)). Plus, you can alter the view count in O(log(n)) to (decreaseKey/increaseKey operations)

For retrieval of the view count of a user, it's more complicated because this DS doesn't allow efficient lookup. But you can maintain a HashMap of Users, so you have access to a User in O(1) time and get the view count. However, as the view count is a mutable field, it must not be used to compute the hash of a user.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of using a priority queue . I need a ranking system for the user based on the viewcount  and on using a Priority queue I would be able to edit the viewcount and insert user .But is there any way by which I could provide a rank or index for the user position in the sorted list as in a priority queue there would be no indexing. So that I cloud acess the rank in O(1) @T. Claverie

Comment: What do you want by that ? Do you want to execute select and range queries ? (select i-th user/select users between i and j)

Comment: I need to get the rank of the user given the userid.  Sorry about not providing the exact use case but the problem is such that given a user id I need to return the rank. Earlier In TreeMap scenario I would sort  the map with viewcount as value then get the keyset(list of userid) iterate over it and return the index ,But it is slow if the records are huge. I then decided to use the Binary Search for Collections over keyset @T. Claverie

Comment: If by rank you mean the view count, then the HashMap (key: userid, value: view count) will do the job. If by rank you mean the position of the user inside the collection (by increasing/decreasing view count), then you can use a TreeSet instead. As it needs unique key, you can define the comparison between users as such: compare ranks first, if they are equals compare userids.

Comment: The scenario is rank by decreasing order of view count and I will go ahead with TreeSet. Thanks @T. Claverie